# How can I deal with "Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a0 = [a0]"?

Tags: haskell

Code:

```
myperms [] = [[]]
myperms xs = [a:ys| a<-xs, ys<-(delete a xs)]
```

And I get this error:

```
project2.hs:66:15:
     Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a0 = [a0]
     In the second argument of `(:)', namely `ys'
     In the expression: a : ys
     In the expression: [a : ys | a <- xs, ys <- (delete a xs)]
```

I can't think of the error in this. Can someone explain to me how to deal with these situations in order not to get errors and write better code? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@bheklilr has explained the bug in your code, but you asked: *"Can someone explain to me how to deal with these situations in order not to get errors and write better code?"*

I'd suggest adding type signatures.

```
myperms :: [a] -> [[a]]
myperms [] = [[]]
myperms xs = [a:ys| a<-xs, ys<-(delete a xs)]
```

It sometimes helps to take all the genericity out of the code altogether, eg:

```
myperms :: [Int] -> [[Int]]
myperms [] = [[]]
myperms xs = [a:ys| a<-xs, ys<-(delete a xs)]
```

If you still can't see the bug, break it down into smaller functions, and give *them* type signatures:

```
genys:: Int->[Int]->[[Int]] -- I know this is wrong, that's the point
genys a xs=delete a xs
```

You can usually remove this scaffolding once the code is fixed. Now you'll have a more specific error, about a more specific piece of code, and you should be able to resolve your problem.

It's a good idea to write the type signatures before writing the implementations, it picks up a lot of bugs early on. It can also help clarify your thinking about what it really is you're trying to do with each function. As a bonus, you can then look up your type signature in [hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%5Ba%5D-%3E%5B%5Ba%5D%5D), there may be an implementation you can use already.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're doing

```
ys <- delete a xs
```

Since `xs` has the type `[a]`, and `a` has the type `a`, then `delete a xs` has the type `[a]`.  You're then saying "for each `ys` in `delete a xs` ..." with the `ys <-`, so `ys` should have the type `a`, but you are then trying to use `a:` on it, which means that `ys` should have the type `[a]`.

Comment: Ohh, I see. Instead of ys <- delete a xs, I need ys = delete a xs, but now I get parse error on input `='

Comment: @VasilisManavis Try using `let y = delete a xs` or just do `a : delete a xs` on the left hand side of the `|`.

Comment: BTW, the correct answer is `ys<-(myperms$delete a xs)`. From the name, you're aiming for permutations here, `let ys=(delete a xs)` will give you 1 permutation for each element of a, not all of them. What you really want is to choose `ys` from all permutations of the list without `a`, so it's recursive.